# Error from Git LFS when cloning a BitBucket repository with eGit

Tags: egit, git-lfs

I'm getting errors when cloning a repository with a Git LFS filter using Eclipse eGit.

git-lfs 2.4.0 is installed via brew and in the usual location.

```
$ which git-lfs
/usr/local/bin/git-lfs
```

Cloning over HTTPS on the command line works fine.

```
$ git clone https://...@bitbucket.org/.../<repos>.git
Cloning into '<repos>'...
remote: Counting objects: 3453, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2289/2289), done.
remote: Total 3453 (delta 1073), reused 3328 (delta 1009)
Receiving objects: 100% (3453/3453), 7.33 MiB | 374.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1073/1073), done.
Checking out files: 100% (3070/3070), done.
Filtering content: 100% (309/309), 197.75 MiB | 1.80 MiB/s, done.
```

When cloning with Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.3a and Eclipse eGit 4.9.2, the clone operation works fine, but there is an error when it gets to retrieving LFS assets:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.FilterFailedException:
Execution of filter command 'git-lfs smudge -- '<file1>'' on file '<file1>'
failed with return code '127', message on stderr:
'git-lfs smudge -- '<file1>': git-lfs: command not found'

org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.FilterFailedException:
Execution of filter command 'git-lfs smudge -- '<file2>'' on file '<file2>'
failed with return code '127', message on stderr:
'git-lfs smudge -- '<file2>': git-lfs: command not found'
```

It seems that `git-lfs` in `/usr/local/bin` is not discovered. If I open a Eclipse terminal, `echo $PATH` prints:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

However, from a standard terminal, `echo $PATH` prints:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

**Do I need to add `/usr/local/bin` to the path that eGit sees? If so, how can that be done?**

3 of my colleagues have the same issue and I'm working from a new install of Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding the following LSEnvironment tag after the fist  tag in my Info.plist file in the Eclipse.app directory. Find Eclipse in your Applications folder, right click on the Eclipse application and select Show Package Contents.  Then within the Contents folder you should have an Info.plist file. Open that with your favorite text editor and add the following under the first  tag.

```
<key>LSEnvironment</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PATH</key>
            <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin</string>
    </dict>
```

Then reregister your application (confirm your Eclipse.app path):

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -v -f /Applications/Eclipse.app
```

More information about the launch services keys is found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html

Credit to the author of the following page for giving me the information that showed how to do this: https://wiki.eclipse.org/PTP/photran/documentation/photran8installation#Additional_Instructions_for_Mac_OS_X_Users